# Databinding using Polymer-Dart and Dart objects

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a custom class called `MyClass`. I have a `List<MyClass> testList` in my custom element and want to use databinding for displaying the List's content.

**MyClass:**

```
class MyClass {

  String name;

  MyClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

**custom_element.dart:**

```
  ...

  attached() {
    super.attached();
    var lst = new List<MyClass>();
    lst.add(new MyClass('test'));
    set('testList', lst);
  }

  ...
```

**custom_element.html:**

```
  ...

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{testList}}">
      <span>{{item}}</span>
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  </template>

  ...
```

However, the output is:

```
  <span>[object DartObject]<span>
  <span><span>
  <span>[object DartObject]<span>
  <span><span>
```

Why doesn't it show the object's name? How can I access the property name? Neither `item.name` nor `item['name']` work... It used to work on Polymer 0.5 and the corresponding Polymer-Dart version. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit confusing as there is no documentation out yet for the new polymer version, but all you (should) need to do is make your class extend the `JsProxy` class. If you are on the `behaviors` branch you will also need to annotate the class with `@jsProxyReflectable`. For instance:

```
// @jsProxyReflectable // only if you are on the `behaviors` branch
class MyClass extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable // from >= 1.0.0-rc.2
  String name;

  MyClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm on the `behaviors` branch but adding `@jsProxyReflectable` and extending from `JsProxy` doesn't work for me. I tried `{{item.name}}` as well as `{{item['name']}}`